# Remote Desktop: granting the session reset permission

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I would like to grant the permission to reset users' sessions on a remote desktop session host (Windows Server 2008 R2) to a group of otherwise unprivileged users. The [MSDN documentation on the RDS permission topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a promising passage on the "Reset" permission:

> **Reset:** End a session. Be aware that ending a session without warning can result in loss of data at the client.
>
> Windows Server 2003:  You cannot set this permission.

This however is not reflected in the [Technet Documentation on the same topic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753032.aspx) nor do I have the respective "Reset" permission listed in the security properties of the Remote Desktop Protocol:

[image: RDP-Tcp permissions]

If this is simply a documentation error, how would I then grant the "Reset" permission? I would like to avoid "Full Control" because it includes a number of other rights which should not be granted.

Comment: I agree with BlueCompute on the documentation.  However, I wonder if giving them all of the above pics rights except Remote Control and Message would handle what you are after?

Comment: @TheCleaner I am trying to find out what I can uncheck without breaking the ability to reset. Unfortunately, changes to the security settings of Rdp-Tcp seem to require a reboot to become effective, so testing is tiresome.

Comment: I gotcha.  You can restart Remote Desktop Services service instead I believe, but it will drop all TS connections.  To help out, normal "User Access" includes "Query Information, Logon, Message, Connect" only.  Only `Logon` is actually required...the other 3 give the user abilities on other users' connections (see if they are connected, message them, and remote into them (shadow)).  However, it seems that the `Reset` explicit permission went away after Win2k.  So `Disconnect` would be the only logical choice left but it will only do a simple disconnect, not terminate their actual session.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the first documentation you refer to is wrong.  Everywhere else the reset permission is not listed and under 'Reset a Session' they say:

> To reset another user's session, you must have Full Control access
>   permission.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730659.aspx